# removing nodes (objects, groups, etc) from group

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I want to make temporary group and add nodes to it, so that they become draggable (because group is).
Then i want to remove those nodes from that group and add other nodes to that group, make them movable and others unmovable.

Group is movableGroup:

```
var movableGroup= new Kinetic.Group({
    draggable: true,
});
```

I want to add shapes to it.

I want to add new shapes to it and remove shapes that was added before these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all child nodes of a group:

```
moveableGroup.removeChildren();
```

Then you can add some new nodes to the group:

```
var box = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    stroke : 'black',
    strokeWidth: 1
});

moveableGroup.add(box);
```

Comment: Does it completely removes those items? or removes them from group only?

Comment: If you want to completely destroy the child nodes, you can call `moveableGroup.destroyChildren();`. You can check out the documentation for the Kinetic.Group class [here](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Group.html).